# can you make changes to a theme in trac while it is waiting for review?

Tags: theme-review

I am wondering if there is a way to make changes to a theme that has been submitted for review and is waiting in trac. I see in this ticket, that it *may* be possible, but I'm not sure how: http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12476#no1

I noticed a few days after submitting my theme that I had left an extra php file in the folder that isn't needed. http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12497 I also notice a minor error in the style sheet - I put the version number in the theme name. I would really like to fix these two issues, just not sure how to go about it.

Should I fix the errors and re-upload the zip file? Will that make the theme loose it's place in line.. It's been 13 days waiting already.

Comment: Did you email the review theme? Do you know the theme review [mailing list](http://lists.wordpress.org/pipermail/theme-reviewers/)?

Comment: I didn't know I could email them, thanks =D

Comment: Thanks again, I joined the list and sent them a message ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the changes and re submit the theme, noting on the old ticket (if you have access to it) that you have submitted a new request with changes. They could reject the theme for any violation of guidelines, so your safest bet is to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not sure how to change the ticket, I created it, but can't seem to access it to make a modification. I will re-upload the theme and hope for the best.

Comment: Thanks again, I sent them a message and re-uploaded the file :)

Comment: No problem, best of luck with your new theme!

Comment: Thanks =D It was approved for the repo a couple of days ago, just waiting for it to be pushed live now. It's so exciting!